# Get all the diagonals in a matrix(nested list) from any position in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, nested, diagonal

I'm looking a way to get all the diagonals of field 8x8, represented as a list of lists

I have the following matrix:

```py
field = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

How can i diagonaly change the values of the field cells from any posytion
for example:(start position is field[3][4])

```py
field = [
  [0, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x],
  [0, 0, x, 0, 0, 0, x, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, x, 0, x, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, x, 0, x, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, x, 0, 0, 0, x, 0],
  [0, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x],
  [x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Comment: Possibly use numpy better? Look into `np.diag`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but try this:

```py
def change_diag(mat, x, y):
    pointer_x_less = x
    pointer_x_more = x
    pointer_y_less = y
    pointer_y_more = y

    while pointer_x_less >= 0 or pointer_x_more < len(mat[0]) or pointer_y_less >= 0 or pointer_y_more < len(mat):
        try:
            mat[pointer_x_more][pointer_y_more] = 'x'
            mat[pointer_x_more][pointer_y_less] = 'x'
            mat[pointer_x_less][pointer_y_more] = 'x'
            mat[pointer_x_less][pointer_y_less] = 'x'
        except:
            pass

        pointer_x_less -= 1
        pointer_x_more += 1
        pointer_y_less -= 1
        pointer_y_more += 1

    return mat
```